# Parsing error: The 'Link' identifier has already been declared

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have two import packages from the first react

`import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'`

and the second

`import {Link, Element, animateScroll as scroll} from 'react-scroll'`

I get a message like this:

> Parsing error: The 'Link' identifier has already been declared

How to handle cases like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
import {Link as Link1} from 'react-router-dom'
import {Link as Link2, Element, animateScroll as scroll} from 'react-scroll'
```

Comment: it's work thanks very much

Comment: Please add it as the accepted answer if it works